# Validating presence of value(s) in a (sub)table and return a "boolean" result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a query in MySQL, on an order table and verify if it has a booking id, if it does not have a booking_id it should available on all relations in the invoice table.

I want the value returned to be a boolean in a single field.

Taken the example given, in

- Case of id #1 I expect an immediate true, because it's available
- Case of id #2 I expect an "delayed" false from the invoice table as not **all** related invoices have an booking_id, it should only return true if invoice id #3 actually has an booking id, meaning all invoices have an booking_id when the order does not.

I've tried several ways but still failed and don't even know what the best way to tackle this is.

Thanks for your input in advance!

**Table order:**

```
|----+------------+

| id | booking_id |

|----+------------+

|  1 |        123 |

|  2 |       NULL |

|----+------------+
```

**Table invoice:**

```
+----+----------+------------+

| id | order_id | booking_id |

+----+----------+------------+

|  1 |        1 |        123 |

|  2 |        2 |        124 |

|  3 |        2 |       NULL |

+----+----------+------------+
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `booking_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `booking_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: can you show us an example of the results that u wish

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this is the base query for your request:

```
SELECT
    O.id
    , SUM(CASE WHEN I.booking_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS booked_count
    , COUNT(1) AS total_count
    , CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN I.booking_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_all_bookings
FROM
    `order` O
    LEFT JOIN invoice I
        ON O.id = I.order_id
GROUP BY
    O.id
```

If you want to check if there is no record in the invoice table add the COUNT(1) to the last CASE statement as an additional condition (COUNT(1) = 0)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66d9a/1)

Comment: Awesome! Looks valid in my example table, don't have the time to really dig into it right now. I'll have to convert this into the actual system that requires this :-), as soon as I have it working the bounty is yours! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :) A small hint to help to convert it to your exact problem: Count all the invoices and compare it to the count of invoices with booking_id. If the two numbers are equal, then the given order is fully booked. If not (or the total count is zero) then there are gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood how the logic works out when the order is booked but some of the invoices are not. I'll presume either is good for a true value (OR logic). I'd avoid COUNT and GROUP BY and go for a SUBSELECT, which works fine in MySQL (I'm using and old 5.1.73-1 version).

This query gives you both values in distinct columns:

```
SELECT o.*
  , (booking_id IS NOT NULL) AS order_booked
  , (NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `invoice` WHERE order_id=o.id AND booking_id IS NULL)) AS invoices_all_booked
FROM `order` o
```

Of course you can combine the values:

```
SELECT o.*
  , (booking_id IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `invoice` WHERE order_id=o.id AND booking_id IS NULL)) AS booked
FROM `order` o
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,   create a view that does it

```
   create view booked_view as 
    select `order`.id as order_id
    , 
      case when booking_id > 0 then true
            when exists (SELECT id FROM invoice WHERE order_id=`order`.id AND invoice.booking_id IS NULL) then true
      else false
    end  as booked
    from `order` ;
```

Then just join your view to the order table and you will have your boolean column 'booked'

```
   select o.id, booked from `order` o
        join booked_view on (o.id = booked_view.order_id)
```